# how to call js/jquery webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, url, frontend

I have a web service
http://itmamhosting-001-site16.itempurl.com/lsc/GenerateCertificate.asmx/GenerateCertificate?Name=saif

It has a Url inside it  :

How to call it  using jQuery  and take the picture url from it and save it inside a variable

I tried this code  to call it but doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://services.faa.gov/airport/status/IAD?format=application/xml",
    dataType: "xml"

    });
});
```

I got this error

> > no access control , Allow origin header is present on the requested resource

Im new to jquery and js ,Im stuck i tried many codes if some one can give or show

Comment: it's CORS error, read more here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

you need to allow cross-origin where your API is hosted

How are you calling this API? I mean using localhost or using file path in browser?

Comment: I can't help you from here, you need to allow cross-origin and your issues will be resolved for sure

Comment: Can u please Answer this so i can close the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://services.faa.gov/airport/status/IAD?format=application/xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data){
            var xmlString = data.documentElement.innerHTML;
            $("#result").html(xmlString);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="result" cols="50" rows="50"></textarea>
```